# amd ryzen 5 3550h fan and graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, fan

I recently bought a HP Pavilion Gaming ec0009ns with a AMD Ryzen 5 processor and a NVIDIA GTX 1050 3GB.

The laptop didn't have a OS, and i installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa in dual boot. In Windows 10 all works fine, and the fan its off most of the time, but when I run Ubuntu the fan is running all the time and I can't connect a second monitor by the HDMI port but in Windows it works fine. I install the kernel version 5.6.14 but it doesn't work like as I expected.

This is my system information:

- Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
- Qt Version: 5.12.8
- Kernel Version: 5.6.14-050614-lowlatency
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Processors: 8 × AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
  Memory: 5,8 GiB

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install lm-sensors sudo apt-get install -y fancontrol

install these and then run sudo sensors-detect

write yes in all entries

then run sudo fancontrol you can change fan speed there

and about monitor
i didnt worked with kde a lot but go to display option there should be something like  extend displays or joint display u should select this , then dual monitor works fine

Comment: Thank you for the answer. the problem with the second monitor also happens with another GNU/Linux opertaing system like Ubuntu Studio or Ubuntu.
t is as if it did not detect the second monitor. My laptop has the AMD integrated graphics and the NVidia GTX 1050 card and has the proprietary NVIDIA drivers installed but I can't find anything about the AMD Radeon Vega 8 drivers and I don't know if the integrated graphics control the HDMI output and that's why it detects the second monitor that in Windows works correctly.

Thanks a lot